# Как применять фильтр Or And в gridview devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, фильтр

Есть gridView (devexpress) сетка отображения данных из коллекции. В нем есть своя встроенная панель поиска где вводится текст, и по этому тексту данные в gridView фильтруются.

Когда мы пишем одно слово (например: test) программа находит все подходящие данные. Но когда пишу два слова ( например: test Timur) он находит все данные где есть слово test и отдельно все данные где есть слово Timur.

Когда я пишу "test Timur" хочу чтобы программа нашла данные только где есть и test и Timur. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните какой платформе идет речь: Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.Net что-то другое (добавьте соответствующую метку). Еще лучше: добавьте [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и ссылку на скриншот.

Comment: windowsf forms visual studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы искать по точному вхождению строки нужно вводить ее в поле поиска вместе с кавычками:

> "test Timur"

Чтобы автоматически искать по точному вхождению в поддержке DevExpress ([GridView - Find panel filter - How to search by full text](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T124410/gridview-find-panel-filter-how-to-search-by-full-text)) рекомендуют обрабатывать событие [`GridView.ColumnFilterChanged`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ColumnFilterChanged.event) и добавлять кавычки:

```
 private void gridView1_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var filterText = gridView1.FindFilterText;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterText) && !filterText.Contains('"'))
           gridView1.FindFilterText = "\"" + filterText + "\"";
 }
```

Чтобы изменить логику поиска без добавления кавычек нужно создать свой класс, унаследованный от `GridView` и переопределить алгоритм преобразования фильтра. Изучите ссылки в поддержке DevExpress:

- Пример реализации: [XtraGrid - How to automatically put search text in quotation marks in Filter Panel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E5086/xtragrid-how-to-automatically-put-search-text-in-quotation-marks-in-filter-panel).
- Ответ на форуме со ссылками на похожие вопросы: [GridView - How to search the full Find Panel's entry text](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T145500/gridview-how-to-search-the-full-find-panel-s-entry-text)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Еще один момент. Можно ли сделать так чтобы кавычки не отображались в панели. то есть не изменив FindFilterText? А то когда набираю буквы если останавливаюсь на пол секунд события ставляет кавычки и курсор перемещается в начало строки. Как то не удобно получается!!

Comment: @Mr201218 Можно, но для этого нужно создавать свой класс и наследовать его от `GridView`. Посмотрите пример: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E5086/xtragrid-how-to-automatically-put-search-text-in-quotation-marks-in-filter-panel